# Cognito refresh token with secret key causes unable to verify secret hash

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am using below code to refresh token in an AWS Cognito application configured with *secret key*. No matter which configuration I have tried it always causes common issue of `unable to verify secret hash`. The input parameters have been trippled checked and the login functionality works well. Can anyone advice on what is the issue with the below codeset.

```
 public static async Task<AuthFlowResponse> GetRefreshAsync(string userName, string refreshToken)
        {
            AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient provider = new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(new AnonymousAWSCredentials(), FallbackRegionFactory.GetRegionEndpoint());
            CognitoUserPool userPool = new CognitoUserPool(userPoolId, clientId, provider, clientSecret);

            CognitoUser user = new CognitoUser(userName, clientId, userPool, provider, clientSecret);

            user.SessionTokens = new CognitoUserSession(null, null, refreshToken, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1));

            InitiateRefreshTokenAuthRequest refreshRequest = new InitiateRefreshTokenAuthRequest()
            {
                AuthFlowType = AuthFlowType.REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH
            };

            return await user.StartWithRefreshTokenAuthAsync(refreshRequest).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
```

Comment: where is your definition of `clientSecret`?